# Interpretation of undefined returns in expo-file-system?

Tags: promise, file-io, expo

Some functions in the **`expo-file-system`** API can resolve to `undefined` (as opposed to being rejected), but I can't find any explanation in [the docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemdownloadresumabledownloadasync) of how to interpret such a return value. What is the meaning of an `undefined` return (as opposed to rejection)?

Comment: Do you mean that the api can **either** resolve to undefined **or** reject, and you're wondering what resolve to undefined means?  It can't do both on the same invocation.  Maybe post the call that's unexpectedly resolving to undefined, along with logs of the inputs?

Comment: Yes, it can either reject or resolve to undefined, and there's nothing in the docs about what the latter means (e.g., why it's not just a rejection, and what the implications are for how to handle it differently).

Comment: It seems like you're saying that undefined response must indicate an error that should have been thrown. I don't think that's right. Say the API's job is to answer some value that is legitimately uninitialized.  Wouldn't undefined be the right, non-error return?

Comment: I’m not assuming anything about what it means, just guessing; since there’s no documentation.